# I'm having issues dealing with HTML characters while decoding a JSON string

Tags: javascript, php, json

While attempting to decode a JSON string, several HTML characters will cause the output to end prematurely. The characters that are causing the issues are"<" (less than) and ">" (greater than).

Here is a snippet of the string:  "title": "Document has a `<title>` element" ...

In PHP of course.

$string = json_decode($jason, FALSE);

I have been using str_replace but I feel there could be a better way... any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities)? It convert all applicable characters to HTML entities. So `<` becomes `&lt;` and will be displaying in a browser as `<`.

Comment: Please share more details. What do you want to achieve? What **exactly** is not working currently? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: <smacking my head>. let me try that!  THX

Comment: No go KIKO Software...   throws an empty output.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a complete string that is causing you the problem. No properly formatted JSON will cause this, so without an example to work with, we're just guessing.